# Intuition behind calling Zero for else branch of if..then construct in computation expressions

Tags: f#, monads, computation-expression

The [msdn documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233182.aspx) for the `Zero` method in computation expressions states that

> Called for empty `else` branches of `if...then` expressions in computation expressions.

Assume we're using an `identity` computation builder which does not have `Zero` defined.

```
let IdentityBuilder() = 
    member this.Bind(i, f) = f i
    member this.Return(i) = i

let identity = new IdentityBuilder()
```

The code below is allowed

```
identity {
    printf "Hello World"
    return 1
}
```

However, the following code is not allowed and fails with the compiler error

> This control construct may only be used if the computation expression builder defines a 'Zero' method

```
identity {
    if true then printf "Hello World"
    return 1
}
```

Why does the compiler insist on calling `Zero` for `else` branches? What is the intuition behind this?

Comment: FWIW, and perhaps unrelated to the topic, but a right-side `if`, unlike a computational expression `if`, will likely work as expected: `ignore <| if true then printf "Hello World"`

Comment: interesting, thanks for pointing that out. I definitely get the sense that it might be related to my question.

Comment: I am not aware of the common nomenclature here, even if it exists. I meant the different between the `if` placed at the top level in a computational expression vs. that used on the right side of an expression.

Comment: yep, I deleted that comment after you edited yours to include the example :) Thanks for following up though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whether or not an implementation of `Zero` is needed is determined by how the `if` statement is translated into function calls from the monadic syntax. If both branches of an `if` are syntactically computation expressions then the translation does not involve `Zero`. In the case
that one of the branches is not syntactically a computation expression or is missing the translated expression involves `Zero`.

I'll go through the cases.

**Both `if` and `else` are syntactically computation expressions**

```
identity {
    if true then return 1 else return 2
    return 1
}
```

translates to:

```
identity.Combine(
    if true then identity.Return(1) else identity.Return(2), 
    identity.Return(1)
)
```

**A branch is missing**

```
identity {
    if true then return 1
    return 1
}
```

translates to:

```
identity.Combine(
    if true then identity.Return(1) else identity.Zero(), 
    identity.Return(1)
)
```

**Both branches are specified but they are not syntactically computation expressions**

```
identity {
    if true then printf "Hello World" else ()
    return 1
}
```

translates to:

```
identity.Combine(
    if true then printf "Hello World" else (); identity.Zero(), 
    identity.Return(1)
)
```

The last case is somewhat interesting because the translation takes place even if the `if` statement returns a valid monadic value the translation using `Zero` still takes place. The last case also applies to an `if` without an `else` when the `then` part is not syntactically a computation expression.

EDIT: I recently did a little more research and figured out that my original answer was incorrect.

Comment: This wouldn't be allowed would it?
`if true then printf "Hello World" else identity.Zero()` `printf "Hello World"` is of type `unit` but `identity.Zero()` would be of type `M<'T>`

Comment: @TejasSharma that's true, in general, although I _think_ that in your identity monad it would be fine to define `member this.Zero() = ()` and get everything to typecheck. But yeah, this discussion ignores typechecking. If the types didn't work out you'd get an error when the compiler couldn't type the `if/then`.

Comment: Seems like `if..then` is special cased to call `Zero` whenever the overall return value of the epxression is `unit`. I added some instrumentation to a different monad and it seems like `Zero` gets called even in the `true` case. Does that mean that the desugared version is more like `identity.Combine(identity.Zero(), identity.Delay(() => identity.Return(1)))`. That would explain why the compiler complains.